# What is the procedure to renew a South African passport in Italy

Tags: passport, italy, south-african-citizens

My South African passport is expiring in a few months' time. I would like to avoid having to travel back to SA from Italy where I am a permanent resident to renew it. I would have expected to find some relevant information regarding the **process**, **expected timing** and **costs** on the website, but alas, there is nothing useful at http://lnx.sudafrica.it/

I would like to know if
1. There is a place to find relevant documentation
1. If the process is obscure by design, are there agencies which could handle this for me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The **Consular Office Rome** site gives no details about passport applications (which I assume would fall within the area of Civic services).

So calling them would probably be the best thing to do.

The [Tourist passport: Persons 16 years and older](https://www.suedafrika.org/en/sa-citizen-services.html) doc file contains information that may be usefull to read beforhand.

- this link was found at the South African Embassy in **Germany**

so may also apply to to Rome and Milan Consulates.

> - Applications submitted at the Embassy in Berlin or Consulate-General in Munich are sent free of charge to the Department of Home Affairs in Pretoria, where applications are finalised and new documents issued, with the diplomatic freight bag once a month. In the case of urgent applications, applicants may opt to organise and pay for a courier service to collect their applications from our office and have it delivered directly to the Department in Pretoria – applicants who would like to make use of this option should confirm this in writing when submitting their applications.
> - After the application has been sent to the Department of Home Affairs in Pretoria, **it may take up to 6 months for the application to be finalised and the newly issued document to reach the office of application / South African mission abroad**. Status / progress reports are not provided to applicants by the mission during the above-mentioned processing period; applicants may however contact the Department of Home Affairs Contact Centre themselves about their application status:  HYPERLINK "mailto:hacc@dha.gov.za" hacc@dha.gov.za.

---

> **Consular Office Rome**
>   The Consular Sections of the Embassy and the Consulate General of South Africa based in Rome and Milan , render an Immigration service to citizens of Italy, Malta, San Marino and Albania.
>   **Civic services are also rendered to South African citizens in these regions.**
>
> **Submission of Applications** :
>    Monday-Friday 09: 00–12: 00 Saturday / Sunday Closed
>
> Telephonic inquiries  -
>
> - Monday-Thursday 1.30pm-4.30pm
> - Friday 12:00 - 13:30
> - Saturday / Sunday Closed
>
> E-mail: rome.consular@dirco.gov.za
>   Tel: +39 06 85254262 ( Telephonic inquiries  )
>   Fax: +39 06 84242237

---

**Sources**:

- [South Africa - Consular Office Rome](http://lnx.sudafrica.it/en/page.html?Id=32)
- [SA Citizen Services - South African Embassy to the Federal Republik of Germany](https://www.suedafrika.org/en/sa-citizen-services.html)

  - [Tourist passport: Persons 16 years and older](https://www.suedafrika.org/downloads/Passport_over_16.doc)